# Cert manager DNS01 challenge for Goole Domains DNS

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, cert-manager

Our domains DNS is managed by Google domains [built-in DNS](https://support.google.com/domains/answer/3290350?hl=en&ref_topic=9018335), Can we use this with cert-manger for the dns01 challenge? I don't see it in the [supported providers list](https://cert-manager.io/docs/configuration/acme/dns01/#supported-dns01-providers)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like google domains doesn't have dns-api yet, hence won't work with cert manager dns01 challenges as indicated [here](https://github.com/acmesh-official/acme.sh/issues/4107)